Fail Finalized (MAX Confirmations) Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed - Account is frozen"
**hello i need help plz
i have been sending my solana to bonkbot and all what i get is lost lost lost , okay no problem , but now i win i made 220$ and when i try to cash out i cant it shows me this pic
**
https://d.top4top.io/p_30286afka1.png
https://e.top4top.io/p_3028iiqji2.png
https://f.top4top.io/p_30284p1233.png
every time i try , it keep saying swap failed
and i don't know what to do plz help
